# How to assign mysql data type to a php var

Tags: php, mysqli, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to read back the data type from a form input (created by the user on another page at another time) depending on the data type they wanted for this input will then vary how the site displays options available on a form. i.e. if they asked for boolean the form user will have an option of true or false, but if it was set up with as a text, i want to display a textarea.

I'm therefore trying to assign the data type to a varible so i can reuse the information at varying points.

formElements is the number of inputs in the form
formIn is the column name
formtableName is the table name
connection is my database connection

```
$elements = $formElements;
$count = 1;
do {
  $formIn = "formIn" . $count;
  $colInfoquery = "SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{$formtableName}' AND COLUMN_NAME = '{$formIn}'";
  $colDataType = mysqli_query($connection, $colInfoquery);

  while ($column_info = mysqli_fetch_field ($colDataType)){
     ${"formInType" . $count} = $column_info->type;
  }
  $count++;
  $elements--;
} while ($elements > 0);
```

the same value (253) is being assigned to formInType no matter what the datatype is set to.
Any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong?
Thanks

Comment: type is a numeric value See the [Manual page - User contributed Notes 1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) For an explanation about what each number signifies. Your **253** is `VARCHAR: 253`

Comment: `$column_info->type` will be the `The data type used for this field` source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php . So you are actually asking for the type of `DATA_TYPE ` from the schema instead of the data you are looking for, so it will always be the same `type`. I think you just have to take `DATA_TYPE` from the schema, then fetch the result `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of the `field` himself

Comment: Thanks Dharman, This is all local at the moment, I'm just trying to get it working 1st and then plan on changing to prepared statements before anything goes live.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, I wondered if it may be a numeric value indicating the data type, but when I change the datatype in the table I still get 253 as the result, so I must have something wrong somewhere, I just need to find it!!